# Unable to install rubygems via rvm (multi-user mode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I would like to install redmine on a Debian 7 VPS server.

- setup an admin user, the only one with sudo usage (OK)
- install RVM and rails, as multi-user cf. https://rvm.io/rvm/install (OK)

  ```
  \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --rails
  ```
- add a redmine user
- add redmine user to rvm group
- setup rvm for redmine user:

  ```
  rvm user gemsets
  ```
- install rubygems with redmine user

  ```
  $ rvm rubygems current
  system - #downloading rubygems-2.4.6
  system - #extracting rubygems-2.4.6.....
  system - #removing old rubygems.........
  system - #installing rubygems-2.4.6.
  Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/system@global GEM_PATH= /usr/local/rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby -d /usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.6/setup.rb --no-document',
  showing last 15 lines of /home/redmine/.rvm/log/1425037261_system/rubygems.install.log
  [2015-02-27 12:41:01] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby
  current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.6
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
  command(7): env GEM_HOME=/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/system@global GEM_PATH= /usr/local/rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby -d /usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-2.4.6/setup.rb --no-document
  env: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/system/bin/ruby: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
  ```

Last line says system cannot find ruby bin...

I'm stuck here. I suppose I did something wrong

Comment: You don;t need a special rubygms version. Just use the one which is shipped with your ruby already (as all ruby versions since 1.9 ship with rubygems already included).

Comment: Wow thanks. that is turning my question as silly one. "$ gem --version" replies "2.4.6"

Comment: but still, I do not get the error. Because that mostly says the system do not find the ruby binary.

Comment: Also does it mean in future updating rails will update gem ?

Comment: Rails is a collection of gems. rubygems is the library which allows you to use gems. These are two different things. Regarding the rvm issue: you probably need to activate RVM first and select a ruby. See [the docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#3-reload-shell-configuration-amp-test).